# Why isn't the TRIMs agreement renegotiated so that large countries such as India and China are no longer considered to be developing countries?

Tags: international-relations, trade, wto

Why isn't the [Agreement on Trade-Related Investment Measures (TRIMs)](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/invest_e/trims_e.htm) renegotiated so that large countries such as India and China are no longer considered to be developing countries? European countries and Western countries being the ones with the most power, you would think that the TRIMs agreement would be negotiated in order to make it more difficult for large countries such as India and China to benefit from the technology transfer clause that allows them to get technologies from the West in exchange for market access, but I have yet to see any change being done for that. Is there a reason why they're taking so long?

Comment: I haven't followed that particular issue closely enough to post an answer but one simple reason is that “most power” doesn't mean able to force things on everybody else. In general, the GATT worked by tying together many measures in “rounds” or negotiation so that everybody would give some and get some. This approach seems to have stalled and simply demanding stuff to India and China is a complete non-starter. That's what *negotiate* means.